# iOS 10 won't play HTML5 Videos

Tags: ios, html, video, cookies

Got an XAMMP / Moodle enviorement and it took me almost one day of work to figure out that nothing is wrong with my mp4 / html way of embedding videos, but that all iPads we use that are running iOS 10 are having this very problem that they won't run those videos.

I googled for a while and finally found this interesting post where I can not answer to because of not enough reputation:

[HTML5 video/audio player on mobile Safari (iOS 7 & iOS 10) excludes cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215098/html5-video-audio-player-on-mobile-safari-ios-7-ios-10-excludes-cookies/40015409#40015409)

They are talking about 'For iOS10, if you respond with a 403 forbidden, AppleCoreMedia will somehow try again but this time with the missing cookies' and everyone seems to completly understood what has to be done.

I don't and I would be super thankful if anyone can explain to me what I need to do in order to make those videos run again.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself:

In line 248 of /lib/classes/session/manager.php change:

session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);

to

session_set_cookie_params(86400, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);

Cookies will now expire and videos will be played again after restarting apache and deleting old sessions.